# Serialize a structure in C# to C++ and vice versa

Tags: c#, c++, serialization

Is there an easy way to serialize a C# structure and then deserialize it from c++.
I know that we can serialize csharp structure to xml data, but I would have to implement xml deserializer in c++.

what kind of serializer in C# would be the easiest one to deserialize from c++?
I wanted two applications (one C++ and another csharp ) to be able to communicate using structures of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). There are a bunch of [.NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) [implementations](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) of it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a class I wrote to convert a .NET structure to an array of byte, which allows to pass it easily to a C/C++ library :

```
public static class BinaryStructConverter
{
    public static T FromByteArray<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
    {
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
            object obj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
            return (T)obj;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(T obj) where T : struct
    {
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
            return bytes;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice bit of code there. I'm tempted to say the unsafe equivalent is a little faster and also more readable still though. :-)

Comment: @Noldorin, you're probably right, but I usually avoid unsafe code unless performance is critical ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've heard as much before. What's your reasoning though? As far I'm concerned `Marshal` isn't truly any "safer". Not that it's much/any worse either!

Comment: @Noldorin, to be honest I didn't really think it through... it's probably just an irrational fear of pointers ^^

Comment: btw, I just tried to do it with unsafe code, and I realized I don't know how... I'm getting this error: *Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')*. Any idea?

Comment: Hehe. Irrational fear of pointers is what drove us to the warm embrace of .NET/C# in the first place though, no? ;) Regarding your error, maybe you need a `fixed` statement?

Comment: OK, it seems that I can't get the address of a variable of a generic type parameter... it works if I use a "real" type

Comment: Interesting... so maybe `Marshal` is somewhat more powerful/flexible at the end of the day.

Comment: I was hoping this technique could be used to serialize and deserialize a System.Drawing.Color struct, but I've run into a couple of problems. The statement "Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);" was crashing vshost-clr2.exe with Exception Code: c0000374, which apparently means heap corruption. Changing the third argument from true to false fixed that problem, but is there some reason why that may not be a good idea?

Comment: My other problem with what I'm trying to do is that I can see that the Color.Name property is not being "serialized". The byte array produced by the ToByteArray() method is always 24 bytes, irrespective of the length of Color.Name, and it looks like the byte array contains a reference of some kind to the name string, instead of the name itself, which I was hoping for. So I'm guessing this technique isn't usable for a struct that contains a reference to something? And if that's correct, is there anything that can be done to make it work in the way I was hoping it worked?

Comment: @RenniePet, I think you can pass false for the `fDeleteOld` parameter; the memory is freed in the finally block anyway.

Comment: @RenniePet, the name isn't stored directly in the structure, it just contains a numeric value that maps to the name: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1ebd3eb171818df7

Comment: But you're right, this can't be used for structs that contain a reference

Answer (score 0):

Boost has [serialization libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) that allow XML , Binary and Text serialization. I'd say it's a pretty easy scenario where you serialize to XML in C++ using Boost, and deserialize in C#.

If you wish to have 2 applications communicating with each other, I'd also recommend considering networking. C# has built in sockets, C++ has Boost::Asio , it's pretty easy to communicate over 127.0.0.1 :)

Hope that helps